# Find the latest timestamps for each column where it's not null

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate-functions

I trying to write a single query in an optimal way to get the latest timestamps where each column is not null, grouped by ID.

Let's say we have a table like below:

| id | timestamp | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | T1 | 2 | null |
| B | T2 | null | 4 |
| B | T3 | 5 | null |
| A | T4 | null | 8 |

Now I want to have something like:

`select max(timestamp where column1 is not null), max(timestamp where column2 is not null) from table group by id;`

I tried writing separate queries for each column and tried to union them and it worked, but want to know if there's a more optimal way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to phrase the conditionals:

```
select id,
    max(case when column1 is not null then ts end) as max_column1, 
    max(case when column2 is not null then ts end) as max_column2
from mytable 
group by id
```

I renamed the timestamp column to `ts` so it does not clash with the corresponding SQL keyword.